# CakePHP deep sorting

Tags: php, sorting, cakephp

I would like sortking by name in assosciate model using `Set::sort()`.
My code look like:

```
$arr = array(
            0 => array(
                'Category' => array(
                    'name' => 'aaa'),
                'Section' => array(
                    0 => array(
                        'name' => 'b'),
                    1 => array(
                        'name' => 'a'),
                    2 => array(
                        'name' => 'c'))));

        $brr = Set::sort($arr, '{n}.Section.name', 'ASC');
        pr($brr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty much almost there, you forgot the numeric index for the `Section` array.

```
$arr = array(
    0 => array(
        'Category' => array(
            'name' => 'aaa'),
        'Section' => array(
            0 => array(
                'name' => 'b'),
            1 => array(
                'name' => 'a'),
            2 => array(
                'name' => 'c')
        )
    )
);

$brr = Set::sort($arr, '{n}.Section.{n}.name', 'ASC');
pr($brr);
```